# Is there a function to check whether a path is included in the path?

Tags: c#

I would like to check the path.

For example,  I want a method that has functionality below.

Two path string is `"C:\Document\test", "C:Document\test2".`

And If `"C:\Document\test" is compared with "C:Document\test2"` then the result is expected **false** because `"C:\Document\test"` is not included in `"C:Document\test2".`

Another example is

Two path string is `"C:\Document\test", "C:Document\test\test2".`

If `"C:\Document\test"` is compared with `"C:Document\test\test2"` then the resulut is expected **true** because `"C:\Document\test"` is included in `"C:Document\test\test2".`

Is there a method that has functionality the above in C#?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Isn't it just a string comparison?

Comment: [`Uri.Compare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.compare?view=netframework-4.8) is a rather nice OO-way to compare URIs including file paths. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/c-programming/url-matching-c/

Comment: John : It is not just string comparison because it needs to know path structure. 
MickyD : I'll refer to it. Thanks.

Comment: string.StartsWith would work as long as you had trailing slashes on your paths

Comment: John : It could solve just by comparison... I was foolish. I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use string comparison for the purpose. For example,

```
public static bool ComparePath(string path1,string path2)
{   
    return NormalizePath(path2).Contains(NormalizePath(path1));
}

public static string NormalizePath(string path)
{
    if(path.Trim().Last().Equals(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))
        return path.Trim().ToLower();


    return $"{path.Trim()}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}".ToLower();
}
```

You need to include the DirectorySeparatorChar to mark end of path.

Example,

```
ComparePath(@"C:\Document\test",@"C:\Document\test\2");  // True
ComparePath(@"C:\Document\test",@"C:\Document\test2");   // False
```

Comment: It could solve just by comparison... I was foolish.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `PathUtil.IsDescendant(String, String)` Method is exactly what you Need. You find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.pathutil.isdescendant?view=visualstudiosdk-2019).

```
var res = PathUtil.IsDescendant("C:\\Test\\Test1\\", "C:\\Test\\Test1\\Test2.txt");
res = PathUtil.IsDescendant("C:\\Test\\Test", "C:\\Test\\Test2");
```

The first will return `true`and the second will return `false`

Comment: Sadly that's part of the SDK for Visual Studio itself.  Plus it looks like c++/CLI

Comment: Why is that a Problem?

Comment: It's not a common SDK. The Visual Studio SDK (the SDK that `PathUtil` belongs to) is for creating _**extensions** to Visual Studio_, not to be confused with the more common _.NET Framework_ or _Windows 10 SDKs_.   So its kinda a heavy approach just to compare file paths